# database migration using Java , Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three databases in mysql residing in three different servers. I want to combine the data from the three servers and consolidate as a single database. Is it possible to dos o in Hibernate?

Comment: Have you considered using hibernate batch processing capabilities (can handle update & insert) which will be faster for you.

Comment: It shouldn't as long as you have enough heap to store the data then grab as much as you can in the 1 go... If its the select that is causing you problem perhaps look at the query plan (or do an explain plan) to see the efficient of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read 1/multiple records of data at a time from 2 of the databases and check whether the records exists in the third database. If not, then write.

Depending on your memory constraints, you could try keeping a master data table in memory as a collection, adding to it from all 3 databases and the writing it once the table is done

Answer (score 0):

you should use Import/Export wizard of any utility you could find on in [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) Community Version